# check for the specific element in the list -- scala

Tags: list, scala

I want to find if the specific string is present in the list for example

```
val fruit: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears")
```

I want to check if `oranges` is present in the given list

It would be great if someone can help me on this. TIA

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to do that:

```
scala> val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears")
fruits: List[String] = List(apples, oranges, pears)
```

using `.contains`

```
scala> val hasApples = fruit.contains("apples")
hasApples: Boolean = true

scala> val hasBananas = fruit.contains("bananas")
bananas: Boolean = false
```

or using `.find`

```
scala> fruits.find(_ == "apples")
res1: Option[String] = Some(apples)

scala> fruits.find(_ == "bananas")
res2: Option[String] = None
```

check the documentation for other useful methods on: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List